# What/When would this regular expression match?

Tags: regex

I was reading about regular expressions (I'm a regex newbie, but want to learn them) and came across this regex:

```
/^(?!http:\/\/www.google.com).*/
```

and I didn't know what or when it would match...so my question is just that, what/when would this regex match?

Thanks for helping out a regex padawan!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches anything that doesn't start with:

```
http://www.google.com
```

(where the dots can be any character, which is probably not intended).

Comment: In my feeling, a negative lookbehind would be more appropriate. This confuses me ;)

Comment: @Felix: What's confusing about it?  The first thing the regex does is look ahead to see if the subexpression matches at the beginning of the string.  How could a lookbehind be more appropriate?